# Finding the sum of elements of the largest sub array of increasing order in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a file named [sample.txt](http://pastebin.ca/2650101) which contains 1000 integers(both positive and negative numbers). First I copied the file into an array of size 1000 (say **a**). 
My aim is to locate the largest *sub array* in **a** and find the sum of elements in it.
An array is a  *sub array* if it's consecutive elements are in increasing order. For example in the array {12,23,3,1,-56,2,4,6,45,49,1,2,-10} the *sub array* is {-56,2,4,6,45,49}.
Then I need to calculate the sum of elements of this sub array.

Given below is my attempt to solve the problem using a C program. 
I'm a non-CS major just finished C programming in this semester. Your help would be very much appreciated.

```
int sum(int a[],int i,int temp)
{
 int sum=0,j;
 for(j=i;j<i+temp;j++)
  sum+=a[j];
 printf("Sum = %d", sum); 
 return 0;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *f1;
    int a[1000],b[900];
    int number,i=-1,counter=0,temp=1,check=1,j;
    f1 = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    while (!feof (f1) && fscanf (f1, "%d", &number) && i++ < 1000 )// copying the file to an array
    a[i] = number;
    fclose(f1);
    for(i=1;i<1000;i++)
    {
     if(a[i-1]<a[i])
      counter++;
     else
     {
       if(counter>temp)
         temp=counter;
       counter=0;
      } 
    }
    temp++;
    printf("Temp= %d", temp); // the length of the largest sub array whose elements are in increasing order
    sum(a,i,temp);      
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: The output of my program is not correct. It seems like my logic is wrong or something.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a general advice, in order to prevent your program from crashing:**

Change this:

```
while (!feof (f1) && fscanf (f1, "%d", &number) && i++ < 1000 )
    a[i] = number;
```

To this:

```
while (!feof (f1) && fscanf (f1, "%d", &number) && i < 1000 )
    a[i++] = number;
```

Comment: changed. BTW the program doesn't crashing either way.

Comment: little question, can we do a feof on a failed fopen, I thought feof checks for the flags in the struct allocated to the file, but if the file was never opened, how would feof work?, oh unless feof(NULL) returns something.

Comment: No. You should assert that `f1 != NULL` after you call `f1 = fopen(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I come from C++ but maybe I can help..you could try this :

```
for(i=1;i<=1000;i++)
    {
     if(a[i]<a[i+1])
      counter++;
```

Comment: Hmmmmm... will access `a[1000]` and `a[1001]`, where only `a[0...999]` are allowed. This is not a very good idea!!!

Comment: I don't think it will because when the "i" variable is 1000, the condition is evaluated to true and after that, it is incremented and now i=1001 and the logical condition evaluates to false because 1001 is not <= 1000

Comment: Ohh..Yeah...Sorry :))

Comment: First of all, `a[1000]` by itself is not allowed. Second, none of the things you mention will prevent the CPU from accessing `a[i+1]` when `i == 1000` (hence accessing `a[1001]`).

Answer (score 0):

I introduced a new variable temp_index which will hold the starting index of the largest sub-array and used j to store the starting index in the loop.

Try this

```
 if(a[i-1]<a[i])
 { 
  if (counter == 0) { j = i }
  counter++;
 }
 else
 {
   if(counter>temp) {
     temp_index = j;
     temp=counter;
   }
   counter=0;
  } 
}
temp++;
printf("Temp= %d", temp); // the length of the largest sub array whose elements are in increasing order
sum(a,temp_index,temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

> to locate the largest sub array in **a**

"To locate the largest", I suppose you mean **longest** sub-array.

Anyway, here is an implementation (it works for your test input):

```
int longest_increasing(int array[], int length, int *start, int *end)
{
    int pos, curr_pos;

    *start = 1;
    *end = 0;

    curr_pos = 0;
    while (curr_pos + 1 < length) {
        while (curr_pos+1 < length && array[curr_pos] >= array[curr_pos+1])
            curr_pos++;

        for (pos = curr_pos; pos+1 < length && array[pos] < array[pos+1]; pos++)
            ;

        if (*end - *start < pos - curr_pos) {
            *start = curr_pos;
            *end = pos;
        }
        curr_pos = pos+1;
    }

    if (*start < *end)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```